# Dynamically arrange UITableViewCell - iOS

Tags: ios, dynamic, uitableview

I have a table view with a cell that gets all of it content from a JSON response.

The cell is structured like so:

```
Name (can be one or two lines long)
Address (can be 3 or 4 lines long)
Instructions (can be 1 or 3 lines long) [these can be 'hidden' depending on what I get from JSON response]
Payment (can be 1 or 3 lines long) [these can be 'hidden' depending on what I get from JSON response]
    Button (which will need to move accordingly if other things are hidden) [this will be hidden if it is the zeroth cell in the table]
```

And all of these lines have different spacing in between.

My question is, is there an easy way to dynamically arrange all of the content, without having to specify the (x, y, height, and width) of all the objects given a specific response, I get back?

I tried to follow the tutorial on "cocoa is my girlfriend" but I'm not sure if it will work in my case.

Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have no issues in adding labels in cell.contentView. All the labels must be relative and you should calculate their text sizes like this to adjust height properly.

```
-(CGFloat) stringSize:(NSString *) str {

UIFont *myFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];

CGSize stringSize = [str sizeWithFont:myFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 10, 999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

return stringSize.height + 15;
}
```

Comment: You need to set the frames.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want something like this(with fixed positions):

```
Label1    Label2                         Label5      Button1
```

to rather show up like this(with dynamic positions for when middle labels are hidden):

```
Label1    Label2    Label5    Button1
```

without having to set frames for every possible scenario?

In that case, I might have an idea you could try out.
As far as I know, both a label and a button (and textView or whatever you want to use) inherits from UIView, which have frame-properties. My idea is that when you know which labels and buttons you are going to show, then you can put those in an array, leave the hidden ones out, and set the frames relative to eachother. Like this:

```
UILabel *label1 = ...;
UILabel *label2 = ...;
UILabel *label3 = ...;
UILabel *label4 = ...;
UIButton *button1 = ...;

//Let's say you later figure out you want to show labels 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4, but show the button:
NSMutableArray *elements = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[elements addObject:label1];
[elements addObject:label2];
[elements addObject:button1];
//Not adding label3&4

//Now we have collected all the elements we WANT to show togehter in this array.
//Let's give them some good frames
//Loop through the array
for(int i = 0; i<elements.count; i++) //In this case, three times.
{
    UIView *element = (UIView*)[elements objectAtIndex:i];
    if(i == 0)
    {
        //Here we set the frame for the first element
        //This needs to be treated differently than the others, 
        //as their positions are relative to this
        CGRect previousFrame = element.frame;
        [element setFrame:CGRectMake(20, previousFrame.origin.y, previousFrame.size.width, previousFrame.size.height)];
        //Setting this first element to start at origin x=20
    }
    else
    {
        //If we get here, we know that we're not at the first element
        //so we can check where the previous element stopped, which is where we should start
        UIView *previousElement = [elements objectAtIndex:i-1];
        CGRect pef = previousElement.frame; //PreviousElementFrame
        //Let's say we want this element to start exactly where the previous element ended:
        CGRect pf= element.frame; //PreviousFrame
        [element setFrame:CGRectMake(pef.origin.x + pef.size.width + 20, pf.origin.y, pf.size.width, pf.size.height)];
        //I added +20 in origin.x to have some space so they're not completely stuck to eachother
    }
}
```

The reason I'm using `CGRect previousFrame = element.frame;` is so that the width and height properties stays what they're supposed to be(what they would be if all elements were showing, the fixed positions and sizes). In some use cases I can imagine that the width and height haven't been properly set yet, so you might run into some funky outcome there. You can solve this by setting the width and height for all the elements before this loop, individually. I imagine that a button is taller than a label, and the same with textViews, which also means that if they are going to be aligned horizontally, they will also have different `frame.origin.y` values. With different height, comes different origin.y. You can possibly also solve this by adding another if-statement inside the `else`, something like `if([element isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){//setWidthAndHeightForTheButton} else if([element isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]){//setWidthAndHeightForAllTextViews} else{//setWidthAndHeightForLabels}`, but this all depends on what elements you are using(labels, buttons, textViews, textFields etc..).

Beware, I can't test this right now, and I wrote it 'by hand', so there might be errors in here. As I said, it's just an idea that might work.
And I assume you're using a custom tableViewCell, with all these labels, so to do this for a tableView, you could put everything i wrote into a method in `CustomCell.m`, and call it from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //blah blah
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"Fidel";
    cell.addressLabel.text = @"Cashflow City";
    cell.instructionsLabel.text = @""; //empty
    cell.paymentLabel.text = @""; //empty
    cell.thatButton.hidden = NO;
    //Now we don't want the empty labels to use valuable 'invisible' space.
    [cell arrangeElements];
}
```

in `customCell.h`:

```
-(void)arrangeElements;
```

in `customCell.m`:

```
-(void)arrangeElements
{
    NSMutableArray *elements = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if(![nameLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]) // if this label is NOT empty
        [elements addObject:nameLabel];
    //Repeat above for all elements

    //then put the rest of the code from above
}
```

Wow, I got really carried away on this one.. I miss the computer I use for programming..